# Code was working and now isn't - can anyone assist?

Tags: operators, jupyter

I'm getting an error saying that "list = list_sum + num" doesn't work due to "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'"

I'm not sure why this suddenly broke, I re ran it (it was working fine before) in Jupyter Labs and now it isn't working properly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RBQi.png)

I am brand new to coding and couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Hi, the error message is self-explanatory. You cannot use `+` with an int and a tuple. Your code does not have enough information to say more. It is possible you have a list of tuples when you think you have a list of ints.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information provided, it's likely that the variable `num` in your code contains a tuple instead of an integer. This could be due to changes in the data you're working with or an unexpected input.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that `num` is an integer before adding it to `list_sum`. You can modify your code to handle tuples and extract the integer value from them. Here's an example:

```py
list_sum = 0
mylist = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]

for num in mylist:
    if isinstance(num, tuple):
        num = num[0]  # Extract the integer value from the tuple
    list_sum = list_sum + num

print(list_sum)
```

In this code, the `isinstance()` function is used to check if `num` is a tuple. If it is, the integer value is extracted from the tuple using `num[0]`. This ensures that only integers are added to `list_sum`.

If you're wondering why tuples are appearing in the variable `num`, it would be beneficial to review your code and examine the data you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample `mylist` is likely defined as a list of tuples.  As in `mylist = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]`.  Your code is expecting `mylist` to be defined as a plain list as in `mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Try the following in Jupyter Labs:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list_sum = 0

for num in my_list:
    list_sum = list_sum + num
    
for num in my_list:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(f'The even numbers in the list are: {num}')
    else:
        print(f'The odd numbers in the list are: {num}')

print(f'The sum of the list is {list_sum}')
```